# Angular ngx-restangular caching

Tags: angular, caching, ngx-restangular

I'm using [ngx-restangular](https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular) with Angular v6. I want to implement a service that intercepts the requests that are sent through the restangular and in some cases, use a caching method.

For Angular's HttpClientModule I can do that with an interceptor like [this link](https://fullstack-developer.academy/caching-http-requests-with-angular/), but as I'm using ngx-restangular, this method won't work. Also in the documentation of ngx-restangular there's no interceptor that is able to prevent sending the request. There's just `fullRequestInterceptor` which is used to change the sent request and AFAIK it's not able to prevent the request and set a custom observable as the response.

So how can I implement a caching mechanism in ngx-restangular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided not to use `ngx-restangular` at all. I created a wrapper for `HttpClientModule` with an interface similar to the interface of `ngx-restangular` and implemented cache by the sharing observable of requests.